# *ngIf is not working like other *ngIf's

Tags: javascript, html, angular, meteor

I encountered a strange problem with my *ngIf on one particular variable **isAdmin** (which should allow me to display the list of users in **userList**). I'm not sure why its behaving different from all the other *ngIf statements in the same component.

heres a snippet of my js code for the component. This is where **isAdmin** is being switched from false to true if the user is an Admin.

```
_initAutorun(): void {
 this.autorunComputation = Tracker.autorun(() => {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.usersList = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch(); //update the users list automatically
    this.currentUser = Meteor.user();  //update the current user automatically
    this.isLoggingIn = Meteor.loggingIn();
    this.isLoggedIn = !!Meteor.user();
    this.checkAndSub();
  });
 });
}

checkAndSub(){
 if(this.isLoggingIn){
  Meteor.call('checkAdmin', function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      this.errors.push(error.reason || "call from server has an error");
    }
    this.isAdmin = result;
    console.log(this.isAdmin);
    if(this.isAdmin){
      Meteor.subscribe("userList");
    }
    else console.log("User is not admin");
  });
 }
}
```

Heres the corresponding HTML

```
<span *ngIf="viewDetails">
  <div class="pizza_details" id="pizza_details" [ngClass]="{'show' : viewDetails, 'hide' : !viewDetails}">
    <div class="row">
      <!--PIZZA DESCRIPTION PANEL-->
      <div class="pizza_description col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel" id="description_panel">
          <div class="panel-body">


            <div>
            {{error}}{{message}}
            <span *ngIf="isAdmin"> 
            <p><h2>User List</h2></p>
            <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let iterate of usersList">
            _id: {{iterate._id}}
            <p>Emails: {{iterate.emails}}</p>
            <p>username: {{iterate.username}}</p>
            <p>isadmin: {{iterate.isAdmin}}</p>
            </li></ul>
            </span>
            </div>
            <h1>Description: </h1>
            {{currentPizza.description}}
            <p><button type="button" class="btn active" role="button" (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button></p>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--&&&&pizza description collapes&&&&-->
      <!--STARTING THE "SECOND PANEL" FOR PICTURES, STYLE, VOTES, AND MODS-->
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="pizza_picture col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel" id="picture_panel">
              <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
                <img src="{{currentPizza.imageUrl}}" class="img-rounded" style="max-height: 400px; width:100%;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!--&&&&pizza picture collapse&&&&-->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="pizza_style col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel" id="style_panel">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <h4>Style:</h4>{{currentPizza.style}}
                <h4>Location:</h4>
                <span *ngIf="currentPizza.location.state">
                {{currentPizza.location.state}} , 
                </span>
                {{currentPizza.location.country}}
                <h4>Brand: </h4>{{currentPizza.brand}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!--&&&&pizza style collapse&&&&-->
          <div class="pizza_votes col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel" id="vote_panel">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <h3>Pizza Spectrum Score: </h3>
                  {{currentPizza.votes}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!--&&&&pizza votes collapse&&&&-->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="pizza_users col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel" id="user_panel">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <h3>SubmittedBy: </h3>
                {{submittedBy(currentPizza._id)}}
                <ul><li *ngFor="let i of currentPizza.userUpvotes">{{i}}
                </li>
                </ul>
                <p><button type="button" id="exit_details_btn" class="btn active" role="button" (click)="toggleDetails()">Exit Details</button>

                <button type="button" id="upvote_btn" class="btn active" role="button" (click)="upVote(currentPizza._id)">Upvote</button>
                <button type="button" id="downvote_btn" class="btn active" role="button" (click)="downVote(currentPizza._id)">Downvote</button></p>

                <button type="button" id="downvote_btn" class="btn active" role="button" (click)="cc()">publish all users</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </span>
```

I know **isAdmin** is true, but nothing shows up. If I create a separate button to toggle it then my **userLIst** shows up. Why won't it display properly when the page is loaded?

Thanks

Comment: Does this log statement fire after you get the result?     console.log(this.isAdmin);  If it does and change detection isn't happening, you might want to import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core'; in constructor put constructor(cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){this.cdr = cdr;} and then where that log statement is put 'this.cdrDetectchanges();'

Comment: Yeah that log fires. I will try that when I get a chance later thanks

Comment: Is isAdmin a array?

Comment: @Rahul it's not an array

Comment: You should (?) lose the scope of `this` in `this.admin` inside: `Meteor.call('checkAdmin', function(error, result) {` since you are using `function` instead of fat arrow syntax? Or am I missing something :D

Comment: @AJT_82 That solved it!!! I changed the function to a fat arrow and it works now. Forgot about the whole function scope for a second. Thanks so much. :-)

Comment: Haha. No problem, glad it got solved :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the span *ngIf to a div. I simple check could be to temporary change the content in the span to a static text ex: hello. Can you then see the hello? If true it's a markup problem

Answer (score 1):

`ngZOne.run` doesn't mark a component for change detection. All it does is execute the callback function inside the Angular error handler.

You need to inject `ChangeDetechRef` and call `markForCheck`.

```
public constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, private zone: NgZone) {
}
```

then elsewhere:

```
_initAutorun(): void {
    this.autorunComputation = Tracker.autorun(() => {
         this.zone.run(() => {
             //.....
             this.checkAndSub();
             this.cdr.markForCheck(); // <--- mark component dirty
         });
    });
}
```

Comment: This solution didn't seem to work. I will try to play around with the ChangeDetectorRef class in the morning and report my findings.